# Converting hours and minutes stored as text to minutes only using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, time

I have a column containing different amounts of time, ie 1hr, 2hr 30 min, 30min etc. I need to convert these into minutes. My idea is to check the number of characters and then do a delete.

For example 1hr is 3 characters, so if the check finds 3 character delete the final character, * 60 and this will give me a conversion to minutes.

I've researched into the problem and this is my code. At the minute I'm just trying to get it to change the cell colour depending on the amount of characters inside it. This looks about right to me but obviously something is missing.

Thanks in Advance!

```
Sub lenCheck()

Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet2")

x = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
For Each rng In sht.Range("G200:G" & x).Cells

    If Len(rng.Value) = 3 Then
        rng.EntireRow.Cells(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    ElseIf Len(rng.Value) = 4 Then
        rng.EntireRow.Cells(1).Interior.Color = vbGreen

    ElseIf Len(rng.Value) = 5 Then
        rng.EntireRow.Cells(1).Interior.Color = vbRed

    ElseIf Len(rng.Value) = 6 Then
        rng.EntireRow.Cells(1).Interior.Color = vbBlue

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: are hours always followed by `hr` and minutes by `min`? Is there a space between `hr` and `min` and the number?

Comment: No this is the annoyance. Just to be clear it can be any of these formats; 1min, 10min, 1hr, 1hr 1min, 1hr 10min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert these strings to minutes, and they will be in various formats as you show above, I would suggest using regular expressions to extract the components, and then doing the appropriate addition/multiplication.

The following VBA macro looks, for tags, for any of the following:  hr hour min (any plural s's are irrelevant);   (other tags could be added), and then returns the number of minutes:  It searches column A but that is easily changed

Should you have different patterns than what you have listed, they can probably also be incorporated into the regex with minimal effort (and minimal code changes)

To use this algorithm as a macro, which will convert the contents of column A that contain hours, minutes or both, try this:  (Note that the "work" is done in an array which, if you have a large data set, will be faster than going back and forth to the worksheet with multiple calls to ranges)

====================================

```
Option Explicit
Sub ConvertToMinutes()
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim MN As Long
    Dim S As String
    Dim vSrc As Variant, rSrc As Range
    Dim I As Long

'Many ways to set the source data depending on your real setup
Set rSrc = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
vSrc = rSrc

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*(?:hr|hour))))\D*(\d+(?=\s*min))?|(\d+(?=\s*min))"
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True

    For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
        S = vSrc(I, 1)
        If .test(S) = True Then
            Set MC = .Execute(S)
            With MC(0)
                MN = .submatches(0) * 60 + .submatches(1) + .submatches(2)
            End With
            vSrc(I, 1) = MN
        End If
    Next I
End With
rSrc = vSrc
End Sub
```

==================================

By the way, here is a screenshot of the results of running the above macro against all the different formats you've posted here.  It does seem to work, but perhaps there's something I'm missing in your real data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ron, I am just trying with the previous answer at the minute.

Comment: @Lancealott92 Mine can be used like a worksheet function in an adjacent cell. eg: B1:  =ConvertToMinutes(A1)    If you want to convert the values "in place", it would be trivial to convert it to a macro.

Comment: I need to do it within a macro, the macro does other things also. This is just one thing i need the macro to do.

Comment: @Lancealott92 Macro version added to my answer

Comment: @Lancealott92 By the way, if you need to color your cells based on some feature, I would suggest using conditional formatting

Comment: It might help to explain what the regex is doing.

Comment: When i ran this macro on my code it didn't work. It change 1hr 30 mins to just 30 and the values such as 12hr it didn't do anything for. I appreciate the answer but I think me how's answer is more what I'm after. Thanks though!

Comment: @Lancealott92 It won't do anything if either the range you are using in the macro is not the same as where you have your data, or if the data is not in the format you have posted.  How, exactly, did you adapt the range reference in the macro to your real data?

Comment: @Lancealott92 And I have updated the code to handle the problem you mentioned to mehow of fractional hours

Comment: @ckuhn203 A formal description of the regex, beyond what I have written above (looking for various tags) would be longer than the macro itself. But you can paste the regex into various emulators (I use RegexBuddy) and generate a complete description.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I understand the regex, but to many people it might as well be hieroglyphics. I'm merely encouraging you to explain an obtuse part of your code.

Comment: @ckuhn203 It seems to me that without a background in regular expressions, the explanation would be almost as obtuse as the code.  And while I would post it without hesitation in a regex-tagged question, in this thread, I think a simple statement of "looking for tags" and patterns suffices.